# React and PropTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shapes, react-proptypes

Some time ago I tried to make my first steps in React. Now I'm trying to create simple ToDo list app. One of my colleagues told me that it will be nice to use **PropTypes** with **shape** and **arrayOf**. I have one component which pass data to another and here is my issue(**List.js** and **ListItem.js**). I'm not sure when, where and how to use propTypes with **shape** and **arrayOf**. Which approach is right? Define **PropTypes** in parent component or in child component? Maybe there is a better idea? Please find my code below, it will be nice if you can clarify me how to use PropTypes. I tried to search something in Web, but I still don't get it.

**Main App.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/App.scss";
import List from "./components/List/List";
import AppHeader from "./components/AppHeader/AppHeader";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppHeader content="TODO List"></AppHeader>
      <List></List>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**AppHeader.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./AppHeader.scss";

export default function AppHeader(props) {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <h1 className="header-headline">{props.content}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**List.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import "./List.scss";
import ListItem from "../ListItem/ListItem";
import _ from "lodash";

const initialList = [
  { id: "a", name: "Water plants", status: "done" },
  { id: "b", name: "Buy something to eat", status: "in-progress" },
  { id: "c", name: "Book flight", status: "in-preparation" }
];

const inputId = _.uniqueId("form-input-");

// function component
const List = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(""); // Hook
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList); // Hook

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  // add element to the list
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    // prevent to add empty list elements
    if (value) {
      setList(
        list.concat({ id: Date.now(), name: value, status: "in-preparation" })
      );
    }

    // clear input value after added new element to the list
    setValue("");

    event.preventDefault();
  };

  // remove current element from the list
  const removeListItem = id => {
    setList(list.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };

  // adding status to current element of the list
  const setListItemStatus = (id, status) => {
    setList(
      list.map(item => (item.id === id ? { ...item, status: status } : item))
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="to-do-list-wrapper">
      <form className="to-do-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor={inputId} className="to-do-form-label">
          Type item name:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="to-do-form-input"
          id={inputId}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="button to-do-form-button">
          Add Item
        </button>
      </form>

      <ul className="to-do-list">
        {list.map(item => (
          <ListItem
            name={item.name}
            status={item.status}
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            setListItemStatus={setListItemStatus}
            removeListItem={removeListItem}
          ></ListItem>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

**And ListItem.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./ListItem.scss";

const ListItem = props => {
  return (
    <li className={"list-item " + props.status} key={props.id}>
      <span className="list-item-icon"></span>
      <div className="list-item-content-wrapper">
        <span className="list-item-text">{props.name}</span>
        <div className="list-item-button-wrapper">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => props.setListItemStatus(props.id, "in-preparation")}
            className="button list-item-button"
          >
            In preparation
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => props.setListItemStatus(props.id, "in-progress")}
            className="button list-item-button"
          >
            In progress
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => props.setListItemStatus(props.id, "done")}
            className="button list-item-button"
          >
            Done
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => props.removeListItem(props.id)}
            className="button list-item-button"
          >
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

ListItem.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  name: PropTypes.string,
  status: PropTypes.string,
  removeListItem: PropTypes.func,
  setListItemStatus: PropTypes.func
};

export default ListItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure where will the propTypes `shape` and `arrayOf` be used, but generally, [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) are useful when you are trying to render a child component within a parent component, and you want to carry out `TypeChecking` on the props of the relative child component.

In your scenario, `arrayOf` and `shape` can be used in one of the props within your component whereby the prop is an array of a certain type (`arrayOf`), and an object of a certain type(`shape`, or `exact`).

Answer (score 2):

Props are per component.

The purpose of prop types is to let you make some type checking on a component's props.

It seems like you did it correctly in the ListItem component.

Basically, you just list all of the component's props and what type they should be.

Like you did here:

```
ListItem.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  name: PropTypes.string,
  status: PropTypes.string,
  removeListItem: PropTypes.func,
  setListItemStatus: PropTypes.func
};
```